# changed its 'Origin' value from 'Raspbian' to 'Raspberry Pi Foundation'

Tags: apt

I have just run `apt update` on a system that has been working for a long time, and got the following error.

```
Get:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease [15.0 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease [25.2 kB]
E: Repository 'http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease' changed its 'Origin' value from 'Raspbian' to 'Raspberry Pi Foundation'
E: Repository 'http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease' changed its 'Label' value from 'Raspbian' to 'Raspberry Pi Foundation'
E: Repository 'http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'stable' to 'testing'
```

`/etc/apt/sources.list` is

```
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
```

and

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list` is

```
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main
```

When I search on line, I find stuff about when a debian version is end of lifed. However buster is still the current stable, and I did not use version code `stable` I used `buster`. Also there seems to be a name change. And most concerningly the suite moved from stable to testing.

How do I fix it? I want to stay on buster (stable).

Comment: And what is the question? Do you want confirmation of the change? I haven't seen that on my updates.

Comment: It's not a problem. Use `sudo apt-get update` just once and it will be automagically fixed.

Comment: @Dougie the message ends "N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
Do you want to accept these changes and continue updating from this repository? [y/N]" This states that saying yes, will make the error message go away. Nothing about fixing it.

Comment: Fixing == Going away. Just reply `Y` and be done with it. It's not going to hurt.